# php variable in bash an send to serial port

Tags: php, bash, variables

```
$arr = array($upsdelayon,$upsdelayoff,$upsakkuchargestart,$upsakkuchargestop,$upsakkudischarged,$upsscroll,$upsbacklight);
$values=implode(" ",$arr);


$cmd=("echo -n '\r'$values'\r' >/dev/ttyUSB0 ");
$out=shell_exec($cmd);
```

How can I send  string in $values to a shell_exec ?

Comment: Why bother with the shell exec, just `fwrite()` or `file_put_contents()` directly to the special file.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the values as a string with carriage returns.

```
$arr = array('a','b','c');
$values=implode(" ",$arr);

$cmd="echo -ne  \"\\r$values\\r\" >/dev/ttyUSB0 ";
$out=shell_exec($cmd);
```

This is assuming you have the port set correctly.
[Setup with stty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242814/141783)